# <ESC> does not exit command-line mode. Neovim on tmux on WSL

Tags: microsoft-windows, tmux, nvim, wsl

`nvim` is not exiting command-line mode when the `ESC` key is hit. E.g., the key sequence `:ff<ESC>ff` gives `:ffff` at the command-line prompt. The expected behavior is that the first `:ff` be discarded by the `ESC` and the second `ff` be interpreted as a normal mode sequence.

This table summarizes the places I've tested this where "WSL" is the modern Windows Subsystem for Linux and the "VM" is an Ubuntu 20.04 Hyper-V Virtual Machine.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **platform** | WSL | WSL | WSL | WSL | VM | VM |
| **tmux** | tmux | tmux | no tmux | no tmux | tmux | tmux |
| **editor** | nvim | vim | nvim | vim | nvim | vim |
| **behavior** | ***unexpected*** | expected | expected | expected | expected | expected |

The first two columns have screencaps attached demonstrating what I'm seeing.

I'm not sure if this is a `tmux` issue or a `nvim` issue (or even a WSL issue). The issue occurs even when no `.vimrc` is used, so I don't expect that my `.vimrc` is relevant.

Here's the Ubuntu information running in WSL

```
user [~]$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
```

Here is the relevant `.tmux.conf`

```
user [~]$ cat ~/.tmux.conf
bind-key -n C-h select-pane -L
bind-key -n C-j select-pane -D
bind-key -n C-k select-pane -U
bind-key -n C-l select-pane -R

set -g pane-active-border bg=blue,fg=black
set -g pane-border-style bg=green,fg=black

set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-selection-and-cancel

bind c new-window      -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind \" split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

The `nvim` version is

```
user [~]$ /usr/bin/nvim --version
NVIM v0.4.3
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/neovim-gOb7vg/neovim-0.4.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DDISABLE_LOG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -O2 -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fdiagnostics-color=always -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -I/build/neovim-gOb7vg/neovim-0.4.3/build/config -I/build/neovim-gOb7vg/neovim-0.4.3/src -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -I/build/neovim-gOb7vg/neovim-0.4.3/build/src/nvim/auto -I/build/neovim-gOb7vg/neovim-0.4.3/build/include
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

`vim` properly exits command-line mode when `ESC` is hit.
[image: behavior in vim]

`nvim` does not exit command-line mode after `ESC` is hit.
[image: behavior in neovim]

Is this behavior a bug or a configuration error on my part?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a timeout problem. When entering `:bb<esc>bb` does the cursor move? At any rate, check `:help timeout` and `:help ttimeout` (and the respective lengths)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The cursor does not move when `:bb<esc>bb` is pressed (none of the `b`s are being interpreted by normal mode). All the timeout settings are the same inside and outside tmux. They're all defaults: `timeout=true`, `ttimeout=true`, `timeoutlen=1000`. I'll probably have to go to a neovim chat room and see if anyone can reproduce.

Comment: Although I think you are on to something with the timeout settings. For example, the key sequence `5ia<ESC>j` which should insert `aaaaa` and then move the cursor down a line instead inserts `ajaaaa`. The `j` is getting eaten.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue? Any updates? Thanks!